# Access value of an UIItem with Teststack.White

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, white-framework

I want to access the Value of a cell in a data grid.

[image: Screenshot from Inspect]

But I can not figured how. Or is there no way to access it with Teststack.White?

```
        ListView listView = MainWin.Get<ListView>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("dataGrid"));
        ListViewCell cell = listView.Rows[2].Cells[6];
        Assert.That(cell.Value == "2"); //But a value of the cell is not available
```

Comment: to help you we would need to see your code.
how do you fill the data into the data grid?

Comment: The data filled in the data grid with entity framework. But the problem is not how the datagrid is filled it is how i can work with the value of it in Teststack.White.

Comment: please provide some code to get help...

Comment: I added the code. That would be the way of how I think it should work

Comment: we need to see the code where you fill the data into the datagrid 
not how you imagine it should work

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with how it is filled. I need to code an automation for the software. And the automation only know the UIItems of the software, not how it works. So i can't see why you need the code to help me with this issue.

Comment: okay having no clue how you data got there. All help you can expect is:
get the instance of the window of interest and acces its data like that.
You can for example acces the MainWindow like this: (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).MyAmaysingListview
these aproaches are not MVVM conform which mostly voids the reason to use WPF in the first place.